# Angular not compiling correcty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get my head around learning $compile but just looking for a couple of pointers as to where I'm going wrong...

```
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope, $http, $compile) {

}).directive('myDir', function ($compile) {

$(document).on("click", "#button", function ($compile) {
 var newDirective = angular.element('<li>{{app data}}</li>');
    $(".grid ul").append(newDirective);
    $compile(newDirective)($scope);
   });
  });
```

I suppose firstly, nothing seems to work when I put it into my directory but it does when I put it in the controller. And secondly it doesn't seem to compile as the Angular tags/elements don't render correctly. I just can't figure out where I'm going wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Docs $compille

Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

You are on the right track to use it , just need some modification in your directive code like this.

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("Ctrl", function ($scope, $http, $compile) {

}).directive('myDir', function ($compile) {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            data:"=appdata"
        },
        link: function(scope,element){
                    var newDirective = angular.element('<li>'+ scope.data +'</li>');
                    var content = $compile(newDirective)(scope);
                    element.append(content);
        }
    }
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="grid" >
      Hello
      <ul my-dir  appdata="'whatever'">
        
      </ul>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/xqgnhXnVoYOsXFhPMbOY?p=preview

Comment: This is awesome thank you! I accidentally missed some code when I put the example in though, which I've edited. Originally I had a button click which added the list item to the UL.. (Sorry should have read my code properly before submitting). Would it be possible to update the plunk to show how this is incorporate too please? Other then that it works perfectly

Comment: sure, just update the question with the html, i will give a try

Comment: updated the plunker by assuming your html , hope it helps.

Comment: Excelent. Haven't worked with $on or $rootScope before - looks like I've got some research to do! I appreciate you taking the time out and showing me how it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your directive is not formatted (created) correct. No need to use JQUERY... you are compiling the html and the data ($scope) but you are not applying the compiled template to your html.

Check this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/eKdIEhyLBViWAOzfWhhV?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', [])
  .directive('compileDir', ['$rootScope', '$compile', compileDir])
  .controller('HomeController', [HomeController]);

  function compileDir($rootScope, $compile) {

      var self = {};

      self.restrict = 'A';
      self.scope = {
        compileDirOptions: '='
      };
      self.link = linkFn;

      return self;

      function linkFn($scope, $element, $attributes) {

        // I am making a new scope because I do not want to mess the    directive's one, you do not have to
        var newScope = angular.merge($rootScope.$new(),    $scope.compileDirOptions.data);
        var el = $compile($scope.compileDirOptions.html)(newScope);

        $element.append(el);

      }

   }

   function HomeController() {

       var self = this;

       self.message = "Hello World!";

       self.data = {
       html: '<li>{{name}}</li><li>{{color}}</li>',
       data: {
           name: 'app data',
           color: 'red'
       }
   }

}
```

Your html is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="HomeController as home">
  <ul compile-dir compile-dir-options="home.data"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer, unfortunately my up vote goes to the other answer but this is still a different way of doing it, so thats cool!